# How to systematically set "ReadOnly" attribute to files harvested using heat?

Tags: wix, wix3, heat

I am harvesting a directory using heat, however, I couldnt find an option to set the "ReadOnly" attributes for all files harvest using heat.

Does anyone have know any way of doing it in heat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply an XSLT transform to the fragment generated by heat and add `ReadOnly="yes"` to every `File` element. This XSLT does the thing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
    xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

    <xsl:template match="wix:File">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:attribute name="ReadOnly">
                <xsl:text>yes</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="* | text()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | text()">
        <xsl:copy />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: For an XML dummy: How do you apply this transform?

Comment: @harper You'll have to use one of the tranformers, for example [Xalan](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/) or [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/). Both of these are Java applications. Since this step would be a build process, one can use [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/)'s [XSLT task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/style.html). There are other tools.

Comment: Here is a simple C# Form app to transform XML http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/308973/xml-transformer

Comment: Update: -t parameter of heat.exe can be used to apply the transform file.